# sort specific column in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

i have a list and want to sort this list when column c4:c150 value changed.
i used below code in Worksheet_Change but not working! any body to help me?

```
Dim KeyCells As Range    
Set KeyCells = Range("C4:C150")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
  Is Nothing Then
  Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C4"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGw7R.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJh0J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that row #4 has headers like:

[image]

In the worksheet code area install the event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C150")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Zort
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and in a standard module install:

```
Sub Zort()
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C5:C150") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange Range("A4:C150")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

If row #4 does not have headers, adjust the range limits.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Sort` statement in isolation is working here allthough it may not do exactly what you want. Presenting full columns as range to be sorted plus setting `Header:=xlYes` makes Excel believe your headers are in row 1 and will put your actual headers from row 1-3 somewhere into the table

So the Sort range needs to be slightly modified ... example

```
Sub Test()
Dim KeyCells As Range, SortRange As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("C4:C150")
    Set SortRange = [A3:C150] ' or however large your data range is

    If True Then 'simulating positive IF
        SortRange.Sort Key1:=SortRange(1, 3), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End If

End Sub
```